# How to call Body.Close() when using require()?

Tags: go

API test has below boiler plate code.

I want to call `resp.Body.Close()` even when `require.Equal(ru.ts.T(), tp.expectedStatus, resp.StatusCode)` fails.

Currently i have script like below. Are there better ways to write this?
I want to avoid condition `if tp.expectedStatus != resp.StatusCode` and call `resp.Body.Close()` when `require.Equal(ru.ts.T(), tp.expectedStatus, resp.StatusCode)` fails.

```
func Invoke(ip RestParams, es int) *http.Response {
    client := &http.Client{}
    // Initialize req using ip
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    ...
    if tp.expectedStatus != resp.StatusCode {
        resp.Body.Close()
        require.Equal(ru.ts.T(), tp.expectedStatus, resp.StatusCode)
        return nil
    }
    return resp
}
```

Comment: Use defer. Or in a test, use `t.Cleanup`

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, to Close() in Cleanup(), I must keep collecting all responses.

If I use code like Lululuc gave, since code aborts in Line2, is line 3 going to get executed?

```
Line1: resp, err := client.Do(req)
Line2 if err != nil {...} // Or require.NoError(err)
Line3: defer resp.Body.Close()
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "collecting all results".  t.Cleanup basically just uses defer, but in a way that handles corner cases properly in the test framework.

Answer (score 1):

You should almost always do

```
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {...} // Or require.NoError(err)
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

http package garanties a non nil body that should be closed as soon as the error is nil.

As a side note, I think you should avoid returning the `http.Response`. Unmarshal it here and return a struct model so you can handle all your technical http layer in this functio.

Comment: defer resp.Body.Close() -- > since i will use require...(), is defer resp.Body.Close() going to be executed? I was thinking execution aborts as soon as require results in failure.

Comment: The only way a `defer` is not executed is if the program exits (without a panic--i.e. by calling `os.Exit()`). require is certainly using a panic.

Comment: If you use the standard http library, it ensures the body is not nil (so must be closed) when `err==nil`.
But the other way around is also true: if there is an error, you must not call `body.Close`.